# Is Tomcat 8's port use interfering with itself when run out of Netbeans?

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans

We have a web application that's been running on Tomcat 7, we're moving to Tomcat 8 and are now depending on an internal microservice for the application as well. We use Netbeans.

I have made the necessary changes to configuration such that I can start the microservice app and then the web application on my machine from the command line. However, when I attempt to run the web app from within Netbeans, it tells me "Starting of Tomcat failed, the server port 8443 is already in use".

I don't know why that port is reported as in use when run from within Netbeans, but not if the same server with the same web application is run from the command line. Does anyone have any ideas on what to check?

Comment: Are you sure that your server isn't still running in the background? I have had that in the past. Even when closing my IDE and shutting down the server, the server would still be running in the background. In your task manager, look for running java apps.

Comment: To test that, I have twice shut down the laptop entirely, then rebooted, started the tomcat 7 server (with the microservice), then the tomcat 8 running the web app. Same result. The dos 'netstat' verifies that it is the tomcat 8 process that owns that port, and the process doesn't exist until I tell Netbeans to run the app.

Answer (score 0):

A quick way to make progress is simply to use a port other than **8443**. That won't necessarily resolve the problem you are experiencing, but it will circumvent it. To do that:

- Stop Tomcat.
- Pick a port other than **8443**. I chose **8447**.
- Run the following command from the console to verify that port **8447** is not already being used:

**netstat -aon | findstr 8447**

- That's the syntax for Windows - I think it is different on Linux. If nothing is displayed then **8447** is an available port. Otherwise keep picking different port numbers until you find one which is available.
- Take a backup of **server.xml** which resides in directory **{Tomcat dir}/conf** (so you can regress if necessary).
- Edit **server.xml** replacing all instances of **8443** with **8447**, or whatever alternative port you chose, and save the file.
- Start Tomcat. It will come up using port **8447** instead of **8443**. You can verify that in Tomcat's log shown in NetBeans; look for the string **https-openssl-apr-8447** to verify:

> 09-Jan-2018 02:07:26.279 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler
>   ["http-nio-8080"] 09-Jan-2018 02:07:26.285 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler
>   ["**https-openssl-apr-8447**"] 09-Jan-2018 02:07:26.290 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler
>   ["ajp-nio-8009"] 09-Jan-2018 02:07:26.293 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 2585 ms

- You should now be able to test your web app. I just verified that this approach works using Tomcat 9 but I'm sure it would also work with Tomcat 8.

As a separate issue, once everything is working on port **8447**, run **netstat -aon | findstr 8443** to see if port **8443** is still being used while Tomcat is running. If so then (on Windows) get the PID of the process that is still using that port, and then lookup that PID on the **Details** tab of **Task Manager**. Here's a screenshot showing that in my case port **8447** was used by PID **2340** which was an instance of **java.exe** for Tomcat:

[image: Tomcat PID]

If none of that resolves anything:

- Please advise which Operating System and which version of NetBeans are being used.
- Add the relevant portion of Tomcat's log within NetBeans to your post.